# Non-default language for voice recognition in Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm unable to force custom Android TV application to recognise non-default language from voice-input. Same problem are in built-in YouTube application (and other). However it works in built-in Google Search app (Katniss).

There are my code which works well on Nexus phone, but on Nexus Player setting custom language doesn't give any results in selected language.

```
SpeechRecognizer sr =  SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,"voice.recognition.test");

String loc = "ru-RU";

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, loc);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, loc);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, loc);

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,5);
sr.startListening(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was fixed in one of Google Search app updates